# Where are the passhash9 algorithm from?

Tags: passwords, botan

I am using the `Botan` library which contains an algorithm named `Passhash9`.

It is a Password Hashing. Now, I want to know where it is from.

who can give me some papers or links about it?

Passhash9: https://botan.randombit.net/doxygen/dir_2f2a81ce70eadda327392ced4f630ceb.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proverbially too late to answer. I had the same question too until I looked into the source code. I don't know why they named it that way. But apparently `passhash9` is PBKDF2 ([source](https://github.com/randombit/botan/blob/f05cd9faf4140c38bbb10758fc010843b6bdead3/src/lib/passhash/passhash9/passhash9.h#L19)).

Comment: Thaks for your answer. I had already known that. I also firstly head of ```passhash9``` in Botan library.